# VB.NET - GMap: latitude + longitude from string goes wrong

Tags: vb.net, gmap.net

I've got a problem with GMap. When giving the latitude + longitude directly in code it works, but when using a string from a textbox is suddenly doesn't work.

Works:

```
GMapControl1.MapProvider = GoogleMapProvider.Instance
GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache
GMapControl1.MapProvider = GoogleHybridMapProvider.Instance

GMapControl1.Position = New GMap.NET.PointLatLng(40.712776, -74.005974)
```

[image: [img]]

Doesn't work:

```
Dim LA As String = lati.Text
Dim LO As String = longi.Text
Dim Lat As Double = Double.Parse(LA)
Dim Lng As Double = Double.Parse(LO)

GMapControl1.MapProvider = GoogleMapProvider.Instance
GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache
GMapControl1.MapProvider = GoogleHybridMapProvider.Instance

GMapControl1.Position = New GMap.NET.PointLatLng(Lat, Lng)
```

[image]

The incoming latitude and longitude data is the same. What's wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Where's that MessageBox coming from? It's not in your code. What are you showing there? What method / event handler contains that code? What runs it? (aka *Missing Context*).

Comment: @Jimi It's my own debugging msgbox, just to make sure that string is correct.

Comment: You have not answered any of the questions I've asked. -- Still unclear what you're showing in that MessageBox and when, since it's not in the code you posted. Update the question, to give context and provide more details. AKA [Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are the results of New GMap.NET.PointLatLng(Lat, Lng) And New GMap.NET.PointLatLng(40.712776, -74.005974) giving you the same value?  You probably need to workout if the source of the problem is getting the point, or setting the point on the map